# Create a DOM from raw html and place it in a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

This Meteor client code tries to open new tab and place raw html in it.
It opens a blank page. How can it be fixed so that it displays the html?

```
let imgDataURL = $('canvas.signature').get(0).toDataURL(); //earlier in the code

      let w = window.open();
      let parser = new DOMParser();
      let doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
      console.log(doc);
      w.document = doc;

//need to append.child a canvas with imgDataURL to a ('td.sign') element in doc
```

The reason I am doing it this way is that I need a reference to the DOM `doc` so that I can modify it in a way that is not possible with the raw html, like appending a canvas and load it with an image which was previously created via `canvas.toDataURL()`

Comment: _"in a way that is not possible with the raw html"_ You can include `<script></script>` element at `html` which should be able to render the image using `window.open(html)`

Comment: @guest271314 parsing the html to insert the `script` element could be made simple using the DOM instead of the raw html. unless I miss understood you, an example would help. thx

Comment: _"an example would help"_ Not certain what role `canvas.toDataURL()` is used for at `w`? Are you trying to set the `src` of an `<img>` element to a `data URI`?

Comment: @guest271314 yes, basically I need to show an `imgDataURL` of a signature in a certain location in the DOM. Please see edit to code posted. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you could manipulate the DOM of the opened window without using DOMParser at all. E.G. to insert a signature image (an "X") at the end of an element with an id "sig" (a table cell):

```
let html="<table><tbody><tr><td id='sig'>signed: </td></tr></tbody></table>";
let sigURL = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAVUlEQVQ4jbXSSQ4AIAgDwP7/03hVbFlcuLaZgBF2OXgKADCgZ1IgQ+ZcAgrx2daKAJaFwFIUMN3TI+FW9FCB0N4X4PgEVs6Q0kdqA5WzwjdQcw2wLQdGmRkSdmO7XQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="

  let w = window.open();
  let doc = w.document;
  doc.write(html);
  doc.close();
  let sigImg = new Image();
  sigImg.src = sigURL;
  doc.getElementById('sig').appendChild(sigImg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include `<script>` element at `html` which renders `data URI` at new `window`

```
var imgDataURL = /* data URI */;
var html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><canvas></canvas><script>
             var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
             var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
             var img = new Image;
             img.onload = function() {
               ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
             }
             img.src = '${imgDataURL}';
           <\/script></body></html>`;
var w = window.open(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([html], {type:"text/html"})));
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/snExZYUSnnGQQgMbSuh7?p=preview

Comment: @FredJ. See version 2 at http://plnkr.co/edit/snExZYUSnnGQQgMbSuh7?p=preview for approach which creates and appends `<canvas>` element at newly opened `window`